# Как правильно вписать переменную в значение

Tags: php

```
$where = 'active=1 AND user_id=*'; // условия выборки
```

Вместо * мне необходимо передать значение переменной $id. Не могу понять как правильно прописать.

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать конкатенацию.

```
$where = 'active=1 AND user_id=' . $id;
```

Comment: Ну нельзя же настолько узко мыслить. Неужели так трудно понять, что человек делает SQL запрос. То есть правила будет **совсем** другие. А потом мы удивляемся - почему весь мир потешается над РНР.

Comment: >>> То есть правила будет совсем другие.
О каких правилах идет речь? Приведите пример.

Comment: Ссылка прикреплена сверху вопроса

Comment: Приведите пример кода, который по вашему мнению считается правильным в рамках этого топика.

Comment: Ну, если говорить конкретно об этом вопросе, то что-то вроде [такого](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_where)

Comment: "Что-то вроде" не принимается. Раз вы начали критику по коду, будьте добры привести свой вариант, который по вашему мнению считается эталонным/правильным/безопасным. Иначе я прекращаю дискуссию и расцениваю ваш посыл как троллинг либо некомпетентность в вопросе с вашей стороны.

Comment: Ох. Не стоит быть таким капризным

Answer (score -1):

Возможно так.

```
$value_id = 123;
$where = "active=1 AND user_id='". $value_id ."'";
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]